# change from document height to specific id

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I have this piece of code that i want normally scrolls down to the bottom of the page for the `#results`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('button[type=submit]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "postpicks.php",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<div class="success"><img src="../images/loading-blue.gif" width="25" /></div>');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow'); <---
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'd like it to scroll to the bottom of #result instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#result').offset().top}, 'slow');
```

Comment: my current problem is because of a safari bug there is a ton of white space at the bottom of the page and when get back results it scrolls the results to the top of the page. is it possible to scroll to the bottom of #results only?